Enclose character in framebox for a given font family and a given font size
I'm trying to show boxes around some words in a paragraph. I want all boxes that are shown on the same line to have the same height and to be aligned.
I found this answer which recommends using \vphantom{A} with smash. This solution is pretty much what I'm trying to do.

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\test{\medbreak \f[35pt]{A} \f[35pt]{B} \f[35pt]{Q} \f[35pt]{y}}
\newcommand{\f}[2][???pt]{\framebox[#1]{\vphantom{A}\smash{#2}}}
\test
\end{document}

However, when I changed the font family to NotoSans-Regular (download instructions below) and the font size to 30, the characters Q and y don't fit the framebox anymore.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
  Path = \string~/.fonts/,
  Extension = .otf,
  SizeFeatures = {Size = 30}
]{NotoSans-Regular}

\newcommand\mycommand[1]{\framebox[30pt]{\vphantom{A}\smash{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\mycommand{A} \mycommand{B} \mycommand{C} \mycommand{Q} \mycommand{y}
\end{document}

My question is: How to make framebox contain the complete characters when using NotoSans-Regular with size 30?
Download NotoSans-Regular
The font family NotoSans-Regular, which was used in the second code block above, can be downloaded from https://notofonts.github.io/. Open the website and press Ctrl+F in your web browser and search for NotoSans-Regular. The font is provided in .otf and .ttf.

Perhaps \framebox{\strut#1}?

...instead of \vphantom{A}, use \vphantom{\strut} or just \strut.

You've specified a font size of 30 and a box size of 25.  I wouldn't expect that to work at all with any letter that has a descender.  Try setting both sizes the same.  And then smash just the bottom: \smash[b]{...}.

You could use \vphantom with multiple characters. You want the boxes to have the same height and you also want the boxes to enclose the entire of the characters. Therefore, you need to provide \vphantom with those characters that have the greatest height in the upward direction (it seems that a good choice would be A) and the downward direction (it seems that a good choice would be y). See solution 5 below.

% Compile with $ xelatex <<filename>>
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
  Path = \string~/.fonts/,
  Extension = .otf,
  SizeFeatures = {Size = 40}
]{NotoSans-Regular}

\begin{document}
\par Solution 1 \framebox{y}
\par Solution 2 \framebox{\strut A} \framebox{\strut y}
\par Solution 3 \framebox{\vphantom{\strut}A} \framebox{\vphantom{\strut}y}
\par Solution 4 \framebox{\vphantom{A}A} \framebox{\vphantom{A}y}
\par Solution 5 \framebox{\vphantom{Ay}y} \framebox{\vphantom{Ay}A}
\end{document}

I used A  and y in \vphantom because I know that A extends towards the top and y extends towards the bottom, but I am not sure if this is enough for framebox to contain all characters in the font. If you ever find a character in that font that exceeds the framebox, just replace it for A if it exceeded the framebox's top border or y if it exceeded the framebox's bottom border.

If you do not need any of the oprional arguments of \framebox you better off, just using \fbox, which is also robust.
